# Is there a way to prevent the debugger from automatically loading an object's dynamic properties?

Tags: pycharm

I've got this class that has a bunch of lazy properties which I'd like to debug to see when they get loaded in the course of the application.  Unfortunately the debugger's variable viewer itself calls the property's code in order to display its values.

Anyone know if there's an option to disable the automatic loading and to only display the value when the process calls it, or until the user maybe clicks to display it?

Comment: Interesting problem. At https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/debug-tool-window-variables.html there's this info; *When a stack frame is selected in the Frames pane, the Variables pane displays all data within its scope (method parameters, local and instance variables).* Maybe hiding *Frames* and *Variables* views is enough to prevent PyCharm from evaluating properties?

Comment: I also ran into this issue on a cached property that was getting loaded by the debugger, causing certain tests to pass or fail. I could not understand how I wasn't getting deterministic results.

I believe finding the program was behaving differently when the debugger was running did help me figure out I needed to prep data for a following expression.

One problem with this is that Pycharm automatically gives the debugger tab focus when you hit a breakpoint which causes the properties to evaluate. It seems like these aught to evaluate to a memory space outside the execution of the app.